# Can any sheaf be produced from constant sheaves by taking direct limit?

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $K$ be a field.

If $F$ is a sheaf of $K$-vector spaces over $X$, can $F$ be produced from constant sheaves $K_{U_i}$ on some open subsets$U_i \subset X$ by taking direct limit?

In other words, is there any directed system $(K_{U_i}, f_{ij})$ that satisfies
$F = \varinjlim K_{U_i}$

If it is true, how can I prove it?